# How to use lambda as STL Compare method in a template class?

Tags: c++, lambda, stl, template-classes

I'm trying to implement a `priority_queue` which holds `A<T>` objects and use a custom `Compare` method/type. According to the [reference example](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/priority_queue), this is my code:

```
template <class T>
class A{
    T value;
    A(T _value):value(_value){}
};

template <class T>
class ProblematicClass{

    auto cmp = [](A<T>* l, A<T>* r) {return l->value > r->value; };

    std::priority_queue < A<T>*, std::vector<A<T>*>, decltype(cmp) > q(cmp);
};
```

But I'm getting the following error:

> error C2853: 'cmp' : a non-static data member cannot have a type that contains 'auto'

I tried to make lamda definition `static`, but it results in a new syntax error:

> error C2143: syntax error : missing '}' before 'return'

Can you please help me with it?

**UPDATE**: I'm using VS2013

Comment: You need to be more descriptive than "it doesn't work", because the number of ways that it might not work is uncountable. Besides, [it appears to work](https://godbolt.org/z/2GCAuI) on at least GCC 8.2.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Its not necessary to make `cmp` static. Instead, you can do this:

```
template <class T>
class A{
    T value;
    A(T _value):value(_value){}
};

template <class T>
class ProblematicClass{

    std::function<bool(A<T>*, A<T>*)> cmp = [](A<T>* l, A<T>* r) {return l->value > r->value; };

    std::priority_queue < A<T>*, std::vector<T>, decltype(cmp) > q;
};
```

Don't forget to include `<functional>` for this to work.

Comment: Thanks. It's working. One follow-up question: Isn't it possible/better to somehow define `cmp` as *static* since it's a shared entity for the class? (btw, simply adding `static` keyword produce syntax errors)

Comment: It is possible. using `static auto cmp` works even with GCC 4.9.2. Not sure about VS 2013. According to me, it should be `static`.

Answer (score 2):

For me `static` works perfectly

```
static auto cmp = [](A<T>* l, A<T>* r) {return l->value > r->value; };
```

For non static... what about passing through a `using`?

```
using lType = decltype([](A<T>* l, A<T>* r) {return l->value > r->value; });

lType cmp = lType{};
```

Comment: Once I add `static` the error for that line changes to: *error C2143: syntax error : missing '}' before 'return'*

Comment: @Emadpres - sorry but... I cannot reproduce.

Comment: I'm using VS2013